# Azure pipeline not running for branch pushes on a monorepo

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

We have a monorepo and are having trouble getting the CI pipelines to run.

Our setup looks like

MonoRepo

- ProjectA

  - pipelines

    - ci.yml
  - ProjectA Files
- ProjectB

  - pipelines

    - ci.yml
  - ProjectB Files
- ProjectC

  - pipelines

    - ci.yml
  - ProjectC Files

Our CI pipelines all start like this

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - develop
    - feature/*
    - release/*
    - hotfix/*
  paths:
    include:
      - /**/<Project Folder>/*
pr: none
```

For the path, we've also tried

```
/<Project Folder>/*
```

```
<Project Folder>/*
```

```
<Project Folder>
```

However, when I push a new branch like hotfix/SomeBranchName the pipelines are not triggering.

Extra info:
the repository is in Bitbucket
manually triggered CD pipelines run fine
Other CI pipelines that are set with a PR trigger and no path filters work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding my error, I was not using the wildcards properly. The solution was

```
<Project Folder>/**
```